# how to remove namespace prefix with node.js?

Tags: xml, node.js, namespaces

I consume a  soap webservice.In response , I want to remove namespace prefix from tag elements. How can I do ?

I want to convert  as example `<common_v26:ActionStatu/> to  <ActionStatu/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex replace

```
var str = "<common_v26:ActionStatus/>"
str = str.replace(/(<\s*)(.+:)/, "$1")  // str is now <ActionStatus/>
```